# How can I make an scatterplot from an array?

Tags: python

I have a DF that have 5 rows × 228 columns. From this DF I have created a model:

```
X = df_nano.loc[:, "ACAN_SR" : "TBP_SR"]

model = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=2, affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward')
model.fit(X)
labels = model.labels_
```

Where labels is an array of integers where the values correspond to the distinct categories:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I am trying to plot it with this code:

```
plt.scatter(X[labels==0, 0], X[labels==0, 1], color='orange')
plt.scatter(X[labels==1, 0], X[labels==1, 1], color='red')
plt.show()
```

But I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: '(array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
            True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
            True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
            True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
            True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
            True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
           False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
            True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True,
            True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]), 0)' is an invalid key
```

​

The idea is getting a plot similar to that:

[image]

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/33781

Comment: Are you trying to filter the array named `X` based on where `labels == 0`? Can you add some details about what is X and what is labels?

Comment: X is my DF and labels are the cluster labels for each point